# Black screen on 'try elementary os' macbook pro late 2011

Tags: macbook

I am trying to dual-boot os x 1.11 ('el capitan') and elementary 0.4 (loki).

I hit option to get to the boot menu and get the disk select screen, but when I get into GRUB and select 'try elementary os without installing', I am getting a quick of flash of 'Can not find /boot' and then a black screen forever. This is on a late 2011 macbook pro. Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

The "Can not find /boot" is rather odd, I suggest following a tutorial in details to install rEFInd and create your bootable usb device.

As for the black screen, this is a kown issue with the MBP and the AMD graphics card, which you'll need to disable.

The last link provided by **Peter Uithoven** (Update #9) here will help.
[Black screen when installing OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8177/black-screen-when-installing-os)

Comment: Any recommendations for a good rEFInd tutorial?

Comment: Honestly I've been looking at many blogs but the truth is the official website contains all information required http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ . It can be intimidating but it has all the informations you need !