# Black screen when installing OS

Tags: macbook

The second day of trying to install an OS on MacBook 2011 (dual videocard) years via usb flash drive or ElementaryOS nor any other linux distro is not installed, even if i select "TRY Elementary" just a black screen and silence ... Google helped me that it is necessary to add in line nomodeset but it is also useless, then went to what is multiple rows and then silence. Can you recommend something else?
Distributions installed on a USB flash drive using the Etcher and Unetbotin, ie when loading them in sight, but then just black.

Answer (score 1):

I think have the same issue! I have a MacBook Pro Pro "Core i7" 2.2 17" Early 2011. 
I've bought a new usb stick after seeing some usb issues during boot. I've redownloaded the Loki image, I've checked the download with sha256sum. I've flashed the usb stick with both UNetbootin and Startup Disk Creator. I've checked with Gparted that the disk has a `boot` flag. 
Some grub experiments:

- No changes: black screen
- Adding the `nomodeset` and removing quiet splash gives a lot of `[ok]`'s but then a black screen with the one `_`.
- Removing `file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed` and adding `live-media-path=/casper/ ignore_uuid`, resulted in no errors but a fadeout to black.

Not sure what else to try...

I've been using Freya for months already on the same laptop, I'm just trying to upgrade to Loki.

**Update #1**: Flashed the USB stick with Freya 0.3.2, removed `quiet splash` added `nomodeset`. Worked like a charm, booted just fine...

**Update #2**: Flashed USB stick with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, removed `quiet splash` added `nomodeset`. Booted with the `[ok]`'s, but ended in the black screen with the single `_`.

**Update #3**: I came the following docs which notes included warnings about bugs in the Startup Disk Creator. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Install_and_run_Startup_Disk_Creator_alias_usb-creator I wasn't sure which mode I'm in (BIOS / UEFI) so I installed Virtual Box, created a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16, flashed the USB with Ubuntu 16 from there. Booted (for some reason 2 `EFI boot`'s appeared, I tried both), removed `quiet splash`, added `nomodeset`. It booted with the `[ok]`'s, but ended in the black screen with the single `_`, again.

**Update #4**: Flashed USB stick with Ubuntu 16.10 (using Etcher this time). During boot 2 `EFI boot`'s appeared, tried both. Removed `quiet splash` added `nomodeset`. Booted with the `[ok]`'s, but ended in the black screen with the single `_`.

**Update #5**: Using usb stick of update #4, when I removed `quiet splash` but didn't add `nomodeset` it ends with:

```
fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA
```

**Update #6**: Tried adding `nointremap` (from: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303621&page=2&p=13547523#post13547523) resulted in same black screen with `_`.

**Update #7**: I checked my current grub parameters, from /etc/default/grub, the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. They where:

```
i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset i915.lvds_channel_mode=2 i915.modeset=1 i915.lvds_use_ssc=0
```

Resulted in

```
fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA
```

**Update #8**: Tried the above, with `nomodeset`. That ends with the black screen with `_`.

**Update #9**: Following the instructions on the following page **worked!**
https://orville.thebennettproject.com/articles/installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-a-2011-macbook-pro/
Checking `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` I figured out I've done this to get Freya working. (Really wish I had a better memory)
This does however completely disables the Radeon graphical card, which also reminds me to why I couldn't hook up a second screen.

**Update #10**: In an attempt to get the Radeon graphics card working I re-read the following forum post. One of the last steps it mentions is running the rEFInd install again in OS X. Doing this gave me the proper rEFInd boot screen which then included one Elementery OS option. This option also enabled the graphics card. So I could finally use external screens again and play some more demanding games. 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2157775

Comment: Update; Flashed the USB stick with Freya 0.3.2, removed `quiet splash` added `nomodeset`. Worked like a charm, booted just fine...

Comment: Update #2; Flashed USB stick with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, removed quiet splash added nomodeset. Booted with the `[ok]`'s, but ended in the black screen with the single `_`.

Comment: Update #3 I came the following docs which notes included warnings about bugs in the Startup Disk Creator. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Install_and_run_Startup_Disk_Creator_alias_usb-creator
I wasn't sure which mode I'm in (BIOS / UEFI) so I installed Virtual Box, created a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16, flashed the USB with Ubuntu 16 from there. Booted (somehow 2 `EFI boot`'s appeared, I tried both), removed `quiet splash`, added `nomodeset`. It booted with the `[ok]`'s, but ended in the black screen with the single `_`, again.

Comment: Peter Uithoven, so now, you use Freya or Ubuntu just on Virtual Box?

Comment: @PeterUithoven You should update your answer to reflect the updates in your comments. As it stands, it does not answer the question.

Comment: @dbxPixel I've been using Freya for almost a year on my Macbook, I was trying to upgrade to Loki. I've installed Ubuntu 16 in Virtual Box, but that was just to create a USB startup disk. Have you tried a USB startup disk with Freya?

Comment: @MikeWild Valid point, but I didn't have the reputation to place a comment, this seemed like the best way to share my experience, and then further experiments. The problem seemed so similar I didn’t want to open a new question. I'm of course open to suggestions.

Comment: @PeterUithoven I understand your frustration - I'm not sure why comments are locked to those without the reputation.

Comment: @PeterUithoven Of course, I tried to install, but as it was described at the beginning of Lent, all attempts were unsuccessful, including with other famous Linux distros, also tried nomodeset and also to no avail. So i give up, and continue with osx. In the far future, I will have to take the laptop compatible with linux distro.

Comment: @dbxPixel besides trying ElementaryOS Loki you also tried installing the older ElementaryOS Freya?

Comment: Have you tried a ubuntu 16.04 live boot? It could be useful to know if it is an issue specific to Loki or exist in the ubuntu base.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts That is what I tried at update #3, or do you mean the not LTS version? I'll try this with the latest non LTS version, maybe there have been relevant updates. (I understand Elementary OS is build from Ubuntu's LTS, but it might be interesting anyway)

Comment: This has Intel and Radeon right? You can try disableing Radeon from grub with  radeon.blacklist=yes

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Yes true, I'm afraid that the part that makes this difficult. nomodeset and radeon.blacklist=yes gives the black screen with _.

Comment: Pressed enter to quickly and I can't edit. Without nomodeset, but with radeon.blacklist=yes it mentions:  
"radeon: unkown parameter 'blacklist' ignored". 
It then ends without the [ok]'s, and as final line:  
"fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA"

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to Peter's answer with my own experience:

I followed this link on Update #9 to install eOS 0.4 (Loki) alongside macOS Sierra. After installation, rEFInd was no longer showing and I went straight to black screen.

To solve this, I pressed alt on boot, which showed me the regular macOS Boot Screen, to start up macOS, then reinstalled rEFInd.

After rebooting, rEFInd greeted my again and I was able to boot elementaryOS without the need to change grub's options again, I assume that AMD drivers (or at least compatible ones) were installed along with Loki.

Comment: I can confirm this works, by reinstalling rEFInd I was able to use the graphics card. This is probably a much better solution than adding all those grub flags.