# OSX doesn't boot on mac after installing Elementary OS and modifying Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, amd, refind

I've installed ElementaryOS on OSX, at first a black scree was shown, I followed the #9 and #10 tutorials in the answer in: [Black screen when installing OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8177/black-screen-when-installing-os) ,in the final steps I was able to boot on OSX and install rEFInd again, after that I modified the following files /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d/10_linux,everything worked fine, rEFInd was showing and Elementary OS opened correctly, everything was fine except for the fact that when clickin on MacOS a white image was hanging and even after 20 mins. on waiting OSX didn't start, further more even when the #10 tutorial said there should appear an AMD allowing version on rEFInd it didn't [image]
[image]

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.lvds_channel_mode=2 i915.modeset=1 i915.lvds_use_ssc=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

The /etc/grub.d/10_linux

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e

# grub-mkconfig helper script.
# Copyright (C) 2006,2007,2008,2009,2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# GRUB is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# GRUB is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with GRUB.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

prefix="/usr"
exec_prefix="/usr"
datarootdir="/usr/share"
ubuntu_recovery="1"
quiet_boot="1"
quick_boot="1"
gfxpayload_dynamic="1"
vt_handoff="1"

. "${datarootdir}/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib"

export TEXTDOMAIN=grub
export TEXTDOMAINDIR="${datarootdir}/locale"

CLASS="--class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os"
SUPPORTED_INITS="sysvinit:/lib/sysvinit/init systemd:/lib/systemd/systemd upstart:/sbin/upstart"

if [ "x${GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR}" = "x" ] ; then
  OS=GNU/Linux
else
  case ${GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR} in
    Ubuntu|Kubuntu)
      OS="${GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR}"
      ;;
    *)
      OS="${GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR}"
      ;;
  esac
  CLASS="--class $(echo ${GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR} | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | cut -d' ' -f1|LC_ALL=C sed 's,[^[:alnum:]_],_,g') ${CLASS}"
fi

# loop-AES arranges things so that /dev/loop/X can be our root device, but
# the initrds that Linux uses don't like that.
case ${GRUB_DEVICE} in
  /dev/loop/*|/dev/loop[0-9])
    GRUB_DEVICE=`losetup ${GRUB_DEVICE} | sed -e "s/^[^(]*(\([^)]\+\)).*/\1/"`
    # We can't cope with devices loop-mounted from files here.
    case ${GRUB_DEVICE} in
      /dev/*) ;;
      *) exit 0 ;;
    esac
  ;;
esac

if [ "x${GRUB_DEVICE_UUID}" = "x" ] || [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID}" = "xtrue" ] \
    || ! test -e "/dev/disk/by-uuid/${GRUB_DEVICE_UUID}" \
    || uses_abstraction "${GRUB_DEVICE}" lvm; then
  LINUX_ROOT_DEVICE=${GRUB_DEVICE}
else
  LINUX_ROOT_DEVICE=UUID=${GRUB_DEVICE_UUID}
fi

case x"$GRUB_FS" in
    xbtrfs)
    rootsubvol="`make_system_path_relative_to_its_root /`"
    rootsubvol="${rootsubvol#/}"
    if [ "x${rootsubvol}" != x ]; then
        GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootflags=subvol=${rootsubvol} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX}"
    fi;;
    xzfs)
    rpool=`${grub_probe} --device ${GRUB_DEVICE} --target=fs_label 2>/dev/null || true`
    bootfs="`make_system_path_relative_to_its_root / | sed -e "s,@$,,"`"
    LINUX_ROOT_DEVICE="ZFS=${rpool}${bootfs}"
    ;;
esac

title_correction_code=

if [ -x /lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu ]; then
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY=recovery
else
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY=single
fi
if [ "$ubuntu_recovery" = 1 ]; then
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY nomodeset"
fi

if [ "$vt_handoff" = 1 ]; then
  for word in $GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT; do
    if [ "$word" = splash ]; then
      GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT \$vt_handoff"
    fi
  done
fi

linux_entry ()
{
  os="$1"
  version="$2"
  type="$3"
  args="$4"

  if [ -z "$boot_device_id" ]; then
      boot_device_id="$(grub_get_device_id "${GRUB_DEVICE}")"
  fi
  if [ x$type != xsimple ] ; then
      case $type in
      recovery)
          title="$(gettext_printf "%s, with Linux %s (%s)" "${os}" "${version}" "$(gettext "${GRUB_RECOVERY_TITLE}")")" ;;
      init-*)
          title="$(gettext_printf "%s, with Linux %s (%s)" "${os}" "${version}" "${type#init-}")" ;;
      *)
          title="$(gettext_printf "%s, with Linux %s" "${os}" "${version}")" ;;
      esac
      if [ x"$title" = x"$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" ] || [ x"Previous Linux versions>$title" = x"$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" ]; then
      replacement_title="$(echo "Advanced options for ${OS}" | sed 's,>,>>,g')>$(echo "$title" | sed 's,>,>>,g')"
      quoted="$(echo "$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" | grub_quote)"
      title_correction_code="${title_correction_code}if [ \"x\$default\" = '$quoted' ]; then default='$(echo "$replacement_title" | grub_quote)'; fi;"
      grub_warn "$(gettext_printf "Please don't use old title \`%s' for GRUB_DEFAULT, use \`%s' (for versions before 2.00) or \`%s' (for 2.00 or later)" "$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" "$replacement_title" "gnulinux-advanced-$boot_device_id>gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id")"
      fi
      echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  else
      echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  fi      
  if [ "$quick_boot" = 1 ]; then
      echo "    recordfail" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  fi
  if [ x$type != xrecovery ] ; then
      save_default_entry | grub_add_tab
  fi

  # Use ELILO's generic "efifb" when it's known to be available.
  # FIXME: We need an interface to select vesafb in case efifb can't be used.
  if [ "x$GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX" = x ]; then
      echo "    load_video" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  else
      if [ "x$GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX" != xtext ]; then
      echo "    load_video" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
      fi
  fi
  if ([ "$ubuntu_recovery" = 0 ] || [ x$type != xrecovery ]) && \
     ([ "x$GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX" != x ] || [ "$gfxpayload_dynamic" = 1 ]); then
      echo "    gfxmode \$linux_gfx_mode" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  fi
  echo "    outb 0x728 1" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  echo "    outb 0x710 2" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  echo "    outb 0x740 2" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  echo "    outb 0x750 0" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  echo "    insmod gzio" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  echo "    if [ x\$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"


  if [ x$dirname = x/ ]; then
    if [ -z "${prepare_root_cache}" ]; then
      prepare_root_cache="$(prepare_grub_to_access_device ${GRUB_DEVICE} | grub_add_tab)"
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "${prepare_root_cache}" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  else
    if [ -z "${prepare_boot_cache}" ]; then
      prepare_boot_cache="$(prepare_grub_to_access_device ${GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT} | grub_add_tab)"
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "${prepare_boot_cache}" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  fi
  if [ x"$quiet_boot" = x0 ] || [ x"$type" != xsimple ]; then
    message="$(gettext_printf "Loading Linux %s ..." ${version})"
    sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
    echo    '$(echo "$message" | grub_quote)'
EOF
  fi
  if test -d /sys/firmware/efi && test -e "${linux}.efi.signed"; then
    sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
    linux   ${rel_dirname}/${basename}.efi.signed root=${linux_root_device_thisversion} ro ${args}
EOF
  else
    sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
    linux   ${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${linux_root_device_thisversion} ro ${args}
EOF
  fi
  if test -n "${initrd}" ; then
    # TRANSLATORS: ramdisk isn't identifier. Should be translated.
    if [ x"$quiet_boot" = x0 ] || [ x"$type" != xsimple ]; then
      message="$(gettext_printf "Loading initial ramdisk ...")"
      sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
    echo    '$(echo "$message" | grub_quote)'
EOF
    fi
    sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
    initrd  ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}
EOF
  fi
  sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
}
EOF
}

machine=`uname -m`
case "x$machine" in
    xi?86 | xx86_64)
    list=`for i in /boot/vmlinuz-* /vmlinuz-* /boot/kernel-* ; do
                  if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then echo -n "$i " ; fi
              done` ;;
    *) 
    list=`for i in /boot/vmlinuz-* /boot/vmlinux-* /vmlinuz-* /vmlinux-* /boot/kernel-* ; do
                  if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then echo -n "$i " ; fi
         done` ;;
esac

case "$machine" in
    i?86) GENKERNEL_ARCH="x86" ;;
    mips|mips64) GENKERNEL_ARCH="mips" ;;
    mipsel|mips64el) GENKERNEL_ARCH="mipsel" ;;
    arm*) GENKERNEL_ARCH="arm" ;;
    *) GENKERNEL_ARCH="$machine" ;;
esac

prepare_boot_cache=
prepare_root_cache=
boot_device_id=
title_correction_code=

cat << 'EOF'
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
EOF
if [ "$vt_handoff" = 1 ]; then
  cat << 'EOF'
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
EOF
fi
cat << EOF
}
EOF

# Use ELILO's generic "efifb" when it's known to be available.
# FIXME: We need an interface to select vesafb in case efifb can't be used.
if [ "x$GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX" != x ] || [ "$gfxpayload_dynamic" = 0 ]; then
  echo "set linux_gfx_mode=$GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX"
else
  cat << EOF
if [ "\${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e \${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch \${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ \${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
EOF
fi
cat << EOF
export linux_gfx_mode
EOF

# Extra indentation to add to menu entries in a submenu. We're not in a submenu
# yet, so it's empty. In a submenu it will be equal to '\t' (one tab).
submenu_indentation=""

is_top_level=true
while [ "x$list" != "x" ] ; do
  linux=`version_find_latest $list`
  case $linux in
    *.efi.signed)
      # We handle these in linux_entry.
      list=`echo $list | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -vx $linux | tr '\n' ' '`
      continue
      ;;
  esac
  gettext_printf "Found linux image: %s\n" "$linux" >&2
  basename=`basename $linux`
  dirname=`dirname $linux`
  rel_dirname=`make_system_path_relative_to_its_root $dirname`
  version=`echo $basename | sed -e "s,^[^0-9]*-,,g"`
  alt_version=`echo $version | sed -e "s,\.old$,,g"`
  linux_root_device_thisversion="${LINUX_ROOT_DEVICE}"

  initrd=
  for i in "initrd.img-${version}" "initrd-${version}.img" "initrd-${version}.gz" \
       "initrd-${version}" "initramfs-${version}.img" \
       "initrd.img-${alt_version}" "initrd-${alt_version}.img" \
       "initrd-${alt_version}" "initramfs-${alt_version}.img" \
       "initramfs-genkernel-${version}" \
       "initramfs-genkernel-${alt_version}" \
       "initramfs-genkernel-${GENKERNEL_ARCH}-${version}" \
       "initramfs-genkernel-${GENKERNEL_ARCH}-${alt_version}"; do
    if test -e "${dirname}/${i}" ; then
      initrd="$i"
      break
    fi
  done

  config=
  for i in "${dirname}/config-${version}" "${dirname}/config-${alt_version}" "/etc/kernels/kernel-config-${version}" ; do
    if test -e "${i}" ; then
      config="${i}"
      break
    fi
  done

  initramfs=
  if test -n "${config}" ; then
      initramfs=`grep CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE= "${config}" | cut -f2 -d= | tr -d \"`
  fi

  if test -n "${initrd}" ; then
    gettext_printf "Found initrd image: %s\n" "${dirname}/${initrd}" >&2
  elif test -z "${initramfs}" ; then
    # "UUID=" and "ZFS=" magic is parsed by initrd or initramfs.  Since there's
    # no initrd or builtin initramfs, it can't work here.
    linux_root_device_thisversion=${GRUB_DEVICE}
  fi

  if [ "x$is_top_level" = xtrue ] && [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU}" != xy ]; then
    linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" simple \
    "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}"

    submenu_indentation="$grub_tab"

    if [ -z "$boot_device_id" ]; then
    boot_device_id="$(grub_get_device_id "${GRUB_DEVICE}")"
    fi
    # TRANSLATORS: %s is replaced with an OS name
    echo "submenu '$(gettext_printf "Advanced options for %s" "${OS}" | grub_quote)' \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-$boot_device_id' {"
    is_top_level=false
  fi

  linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" advanced \
              "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}"
  for supported_init in ${SUPPORTED_INITS}; do
    init_path="${supported_init#*:}"
    if [ -x "${init_path}" ] && [ "$(readlink -f /sbin/init)" != "${init_path}" ]; then
      linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" "init-${supported_init%%:*}" \
          "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT} init=${init_path}"
    fi
  done
  if [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY}" != "xtrue" ]; then
    linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" recovery \
                "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX}"
  fi

  list=`echo $list | tr ' ' '\n' | fgrep -vx "$linux" | tr '\n' ' '`
done

# If at least one kernel was found, then we need to
# add a closing '}' for the submenu command.
if [ x"$is_top_level" != xtrue ]; then
  echo '}'
fi

echo "$title_correction_code"
```

where the edited lines are:

```
fi
      echo "    outb 0x728 1" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"

      echo "    outb 0x710 2" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
      echo "    outb 0x740 2" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
      echo "    outb 0x750 0" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
      echo "    insmod gzio" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
      echo "    if [ x\$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"**
```